# Apple TestFlight iOS 8 - What is the limit for external beta testers?

Tags: ios

I have an iOS developer account and I would like to test 2 apps with the new Apple TestFlight service. Is the 1000 limit for external testers per app or per developer account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

developers can invite 1,000 testers per application, with different testers for separate apps. Up to 10 apps can be tested at a time, internally or externally.

Answer (score 1):

As of November 13. 2015. there are some changes occurred in iTunesConnect:

> To make your TestFlight experience even better, we’ve made some
>   significant changes. You can now invite up to 2000 external testers
>   and up to 25 internal testers per app. You can also test up to 100
>   apps at the same time for up to 60 days, and submit up to 6 updates
>   per day to your external testers.

So, right now we can invite 2000 external testers per app.